# Firefox new Date() works for invalid date

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I run this in the Firefox console:

`new Date('25/04/2016')`

it creates the following date:

`Date 2018-01-04T05:00:00.000Z`

It seems to be attempting to add 25 months from `01/04/2016` and ending up at `01/04/2018`. Is this expected behavior? I would have expected it to result in an error instead of attempting to parse a nonsensical date.

Chrome returns an invalid date.

Comment: browsers can do whatever they want. parse a standard format for reliability.

Comment: "browsers can do whatever they want" - classic @dandavis

Comment: by which i mean that the non-standard format(s) `Date()` must parse is not regulated by ECMA... stick with ISO, and UTC string dates, like the ones JSON uses for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further clarification - when using the Date constructor with a single string parameter, this is equivalent to using Date.parse.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

> invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided, e.g.:

```
// Non-ISO string with invalid date values
new Date('23/25/2014');
```

> will be treated as a local date of 25 November, 2015 in Firefox 30 and
>   an invalid date in Safari 7.

Original answer follows:

That is indeed expected behavior in Firefox.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new Date(2014, 1, 1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (note that the month is 0-based). Similarly for other values: new Date(2013, 2, 1, 0, 70) is equivalent to new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10) which both create a date for 2013-03-01T01:10:00.

Updated as suggested by commentary:

Further documentation from same source:

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies

So, yes different browsers = different results when you use a string, therefore doing so is discouraged.

Comment: Date() can parse any format it can output, so it's a bit mis-leading to imply that JSON "dates" or `.toISOString()`s are "strongly discouraged" or un-parsable...

Comment: "Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument..."
In perfect world this rule should not be applied here, as in his example Date constructor is called with exactly one argument, which is typeof string '25/04/2016'.